# Save cell name and use it later for range

Tags: excel, vba

This is a very basic Excel VBA macro question.

I want to save the current cell to a variable.

And later want to use that variable to select a range of that cell into 4 adjacent cells.

So far I have:

```
Dim StartCell As Object
Set StartCell = ActiveCell
Range("StartCell.Name:StartCell.Name.Offset(0,4)").Select
```

Obviously it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `StartCell.Resize(,4).Select`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = ActiveCell
StartCell.Resize(1,4).Select
```

Comment: Thank you very much